# Using OnStateChanged listener simultaneously with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, kotlin, view, listener

I am implementing a rotary knob based on [this library](https://github.com/BeppiMenozzi/Knob).
This View comes with a onStateChanged listener that tells me the current position of the knob.

```
val knob = findViewById<View>(R.id.knob) as Knob
knob.setOnStateChanged(object: Knob.OnStateChanged{
    override fun onState(state: Int) {
        // do stuff    
    }    
})
```

In addition to that, I want to know when the user is no longer pressing/holding the knob (similar to a button release). I tried to achieve this with a onTouch listener.

```
knob.setOnTouchListener(object: View.OnTouchListener{
    override fun onTouch(view: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        // do stuff
    }
})
```

Problem: When I add a second onTouch listener, it is no longer possible to hold and rotate the view for some reason. I do not know whether this is a problem of this particular library or Android in general.

Any suggestions on how to implement the wanted features?

Answer (score 0):

A view can only have a single OnTouchListener. Unfortunately, the author of that library implemented some of its functionality using an OnTouchListener, which prevents users from using an OnTouchListener.

An alternative for you would be to subclass Knob and override `onMotionEvent`, like this:

```
class MyKnob: Knob {

    constructor(context: Context): super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int): super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int): super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val result = super.onTouchEvent(event)
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // User released knob
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

Then you'd need to use this class in your layout instead of the original Knob class.

Comment: Replacing the existing view with the custom one works, but how do I invoke the overridden function? Code inside the if-statement is not executed for some reason. Also, when I get a reference by calling findViewById(), how can I override onTouchEvent in my Activities?

Comment: Additional information: When I place the line Log.i("Cutom Knob","onTouchEvent() ${event.action}") inside onTouchEvent, then the console will only ever show the event with the ID "0", which is equal do ACTION_DOWN according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_DOWN.